Freebsd rc.d daemon args mssing
I am making a freebsd rc.d script for a java application, here's my rc.d script
#!/bin/sh
#
# PROVIDE: peerbanhelper
# REQUIRE: LOGIN
# KEYWORD: shutdown

. /etc/rc.subr

name="peerbanhelper"
rcvar=peerbanhelper_enable

load_rc_config $name

: ${peerbanhelper_enable:=NO}
: ${peerbanhelper_user:="root"}
: ${peerbanhelper_dir:="/usr/local/etc/peerbanhelper"}
: ${peerbanhelper_command:="/usr/local/bin/java"}
: ${peerbanhelper_classpath:="/usr/local/lib/peerbanhelper/PeerBanHelper.jar"}
: ${peerbanhelper_jvm_flags:="-Dpbh.datadir=${peerbanhelper_dir} -Xmx386M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+ShrinkHeapInSteps -jar ${peerbanhelper_classpath}"}

command="/usr/sbin/daemon"
command_args="-f -p /var/run/${name}.pid -u ${peerbanhelper_user} ${peerbanhelper_command} ${peerbanhelper_jvm_flags}"
# this is for debug only
echo "run command: ${command} ${command_args}"
run_rc_command "$1" 

And if I try to run this script, i got:
root@freebsd:~/PeerBanHelper # service peerbanhelper onestart
run command: /usr/sbin/daemon -f -p /var/run/peerbanhelper.pid -u root /usr/local/bin/java 
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/peerbanhelper: DEBUG: checkyesno: peerbanhelper_enable is set to YES.
Starting peerbanhelper.
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/peerbanhelper: DEBUG: run_rc_command: doit:  limits -C daemon   /usr/sbin/daemon -Dpbh.datadir=/usr/local/etc/peerbanhelper -Xmx386M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+ShrinkHeapInSteps -jar /usr/local/lib/peerbanhelper/PeerBanHelper.jar -f -p /var/run/peerbanhelper.pid -u root /usr/local/bin/java 
daemon: invalid option -- D
usage: daemon [-cfHrS] [-p child_pidfile] [-P supervisor_pidfile]
              [-u user] [-o output_file] [-t title]
              [-l syslog_facility] [-s syslog_priority]
              [-T syslog_tag] [-m output_mask] [-R restart_delay_secs]
command arguments ...
  --change-dir         -c         Change the current working directory to root
  --close-fds          -f         Set stdin, stdout, stderr to /dev/null
  --sighup             -H         Close and re-open output file on SIGHUP
  --syslog             -S         Send output to syslog
  --output-file        -o <file>  Append output of the child process to file
  --output-mask        -m <mask>  What to send to syslog/file
                                  1=stdout, 2=stderr, 3=both
  --child-pidfile      -p <file>  Write PID of the child process to file
  --supervisor-pidfile -P <file>  Write PID of the supervisor process to file
  --restart            -r         Restart child if it terminates (1 sec delay)
  --restart-delay      -R <N>     Restart child if it terminates after N sec
  --title              -t <title> Set the title of the supervisor process
  --user               -u <user>  Drop privileges, run as given user
  --syslog-priority    -s <prio>  Set syslog priority
  --syslog-facility    -l <flty>  Set syslog facility
  --syslog-tag         -T <tag>   Set syslog tag
  --help               -h         Show this help

As the debug output show, the args between /usr/sbin/daemon and ${peerbanhelper_jvm_flags} disappered! Is there any wrong with my script?
If i change the command to /usr/local/bin/java, it works. But I want this application run as a daemon, so I must use it.

I think you are calling load_rc_config $name too early. It probably needs to be called after all the variables are defined. I usually place it immediately above the run_rc_command "$1" line.

thanks, this is written by gpt...  let me have a try

I have tried with your advice and it works. Thanks
